# How to make bullet move in direction of cursor in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am creating a 2D game and trying to make bullet move towards the cursor. I'm not sure how to do this is what I cuurently have

```
let xDist = this.game.input.mousePointer.x - this.x;
let yDist = this.game.input.mousePointer.y - this.y;
let angle = Math.atan(yDist/xDist);

this.projectile_sprite.setVelocityX(yDist);
this.projectile_sprite.setVelocityY(xDist);
```

The projectile moves faster when its further away which is not what I desire. How do I fix this?

Comment: This thread may be helpful https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/38533-angle-to-mouse-pointer-on-phaser-3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Phaser, velocity is basically the speed at which your object travels towards an unspecified point. You are setting the velocity of your projectile to the distance between the object and the cursor, so when the cursor is further from the object it will have a higher velocity and thus, move faster.

Instead, you want to find the position of the cursor and set your projectile object moving towards that point. Since you're using `setVelocityX()` I'm assuming you are using a built-in physics library, so it should be as simple as this:

```
this.physics.moveTo(this.projectile_sprite, this.game.input.mousePointer.x,
  this.game.input.mousePointer.y);
```